# How to show windows form while running the process using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, user-interface

I want to show the windows form while I do the process. 
I try this, but It only show the form, but the process is not running until I close the form.
Anyone can give idea please.
Thank you

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
$form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.WindowState = 'Maximized'
$Form.ControlBox = $false
$file = Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\picture.png"
$img = [Drawing.Image]::FromFile($file)
$form.BackgroundImage = $img
$form.BackgroundImageLayout = 'Center'
$Form.BackColor = "#ffffff"
[void]$Form.ShowDialog()

Function AAA
{
##process
}

Function BB
{
  ##process
}

$random = ([char[]]([char]'A'..[char]'Z') + 0..9 | sort {get-random})[0..7] -join ''
Write-Host "Random: $random"
Start-Sleep -s 2
$Exit = "0"
```

Comment: Use `[void]$Form.Show()` and when done `$Form.Close()` instead of `[void]$Form.ShowDialog()`, because the latter shows the form modally, meaning it has to close before the rest of the script runs. Remove the form from memory with `$Form.Dispose()` when it is no longer needed.

Comment: But, my gui form contain of button, the button can not press if I use `[void]$Form.Show()` but if I use `[void]$Form.ShowDialog()` , the button can press but, it does not show @Theo